# Unexpected reversed voltage over shunt resistor

Tags: sensor, i2c, current-measurement, power-consumption

I'm trying to measure the current consumption of an accelerometer using a 1kOhm shunt at Vdd. I've read that there's a ~30kOhm resistor at SA0, so grounding it causes a much higher current draw.

When I indeed ground SA0, I see 100mV over the shunt. However, when it's connected to Vdd, I see -36mV over the shunt (measured using a UNI-T UT39A multimeter). The device works correctly, but this negative voltage doesn't seem right.

Does anyone know why pulling SA0 high causes a reversed current draw?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've also tried 100R and 10R.

Here's the schematic. Note that I've picked a random part to represent the sensor. The idea is to indicate that the shunt is on the Vdd line.

[image]

Comment: Try reversing the meter leads. In fact it should not matter.. just disregard the sign for this measurement. The voltage across any shunt is the result of current flow.. It's all relative.

Comment: But I already have the leads connected as they should be. Why should the sign not matter? The sign shouldn't be disregarded - right? Doesn't a negative value mean reverse current?

Comment: What more did you connect? Have you attached anything else to the accelerometer? a microcontroller, a voltmeter, anything?

Comment: @frarugi87 Yes, I'm driving it with an Arduino. The accelerometer is powered by the Arduino's 3.3V line. I'm using a multimeter to measure the voltage across the shunt. That's all there is.

Comment: A 5V arduino? Did you put a 5 to 3.3V level translator between the two? (i mean on the data lines, not on the power lines)

Comment: Yes, I'm using a 5v to 3.3v level shifter for the data lines.

Comment: And is the voltage on the data lines higher than the actual supply of the accelerometer or it is equal/lower?

Comment: On the accelerometer data lines, I mean. Because I think that you are pushing a high voltage from the data lines to the vcc pin, so you are actually not powering the IC from the 3.3V rail but rather from the voltage level translator..

Comment: @frarugi87 Oh! I'll double check that and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Your shunt resistor is way too high, to measure properly, you need a low value resistor and a differential amplifier.

In your test setup, the voltage drop on the shunt resistor might be too high for the component to operate properly.

There are off the shelf products that implement this capability.

Comment: I've tried a 100R though, and it's still a negative voltage (-3.6mV). With a 10R, it's -0.3mV. The shunt value doesn't seem to change the polarity.

Comment: Which way round are your leads?

Comment: The leads are correctly connected. Black into the COM port and to the supposed low end of the shunt.

Comment: @Kar: what is the "supposed low end of the shunt"? that at the voltage source or that at the DUT?

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's the node between the shunt and Vdd. The shunt is connected in series with the low side connected to Vdd and the high side to voltage source.

Comment: Please post a schematic of your test setup.

Comment: I've updated my post with the schematic. It's very simple and I've picked a random part to represent the sensor for indicating that the shunt is on the Vdd line.